# map[T]struct{} and map[T]bool in golang

Tags: go

What's the difference? Is `map[T]bool` optimized to `map[T]struct{}`? Which is the best practice in Go?

Perhaps the best reason to use `map[T]struct{}` is that you don't have to answer the question "what does it mean if the value is `false`"?

Comment: How could you "optimize" a `bool` which has two states (true and false) to `struct{}` which has just one state?

Comment: YAR, can not optimize it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From "The Go Programming Language":

> The struct type with no fields is called the empty struct, written
>   `struct{}`. It has size zero and carries no information but may be
>   useful nonetheless. Some Go programmers use it instead of bool as the
>   value type of a map that represents a set, to emphasize that only the
>   keys are significant, but the space saving is marginal and the syntax
>   more cumbersome, so we generally avoid it.

If you use `bool` testing for presence in the "set" is slightly nicer since you can just say:

```
if mySet["something"] {
    /* .. */
}
```

Comment: Honestly it depends on how big your set is, also `if _, ok := mySet["x"]; ok {}` isn't that hard to type.

Comment: @OneOfOne You're right of course. As always this isn't a hard-and-fast rule.

Answer (score 1):

Difference is in memory requirements. Under the bonnet empty struct is not a pointer but a special value to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

An empty struct is a struct type like any other. All the properties you are used to with normal structs apply equally to the empty struct. You can declare an array of `structs{}`s, but they of course consume no storage.

```
var x [100]struct{}
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(x)) // prints 0
```

If empty structs hold no data, it is not possible to determine if two `struct{}` values are different.

Considering the above statements it means that we may use them as method receivers.

```
type S struct{}

func (s *S) addr() { fmt.Printf("%p\n", s) }

func main() {
        var a, b S
        a.addr() // 0x1beeb0
        b.addr() // 0x1beeb0
}
```